# Strict integer-only if/then loops

Tags: java, string, input, strict

Using Java to compile a code that takes in any input, from strings to doubles, floats, integers, etc., but can only process based on integers. If it receives a double, float, or a string, it will just produce a message prompting the user to try again. I'm not sure exactly how to get this rolling, so here's my current code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sand
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   int firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt;

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Hi. I'm going to be asking you for three integers in just a moment.");
   System.out.println("An integer is defined as a WHOLE number that's not a fraction or decimal.");
   System.out.println("I swear to you, I will go off if you put in a non-whole number...");
   System.out.println("Okay go ahead and type in the first of the three integers:");

   if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
   {
       firstInt = keyboard.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Red.");
       System.out.println("So the first integer is " + firstInt);
       System.out.println("Okay go ahead and type in the second of the three integers: ");
       if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
       {
           secondInt = keyboard.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Green.");
           System.out.println("So the first and second integers are " + firstInt + " and " + secondInt);
       }

       else
       {
           System.out.println("Orange.");
           System.out.println("Please try again.");
       }
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Blue.");
       System.out.println("Please try again.");
   }
   }
}
```

I have orange and blue representing times in which there are some input errors, but it's not complete. I'm not sure how to approach this, be it a while loop or a for loop or a try/catch. I'm new when it comes to learning Java so some #notes would be helpful along the way. The code is to designed to read three numbers that are integers from the user in a string. That's straightforward, but analyzing the input is where I'm struggling.

Comment: "The code is to designed to read three numbers that are integers from the user in a string" - Are you trying to extract first 3 ints that occur in a string which the user inputs. ex - if input is - "1 year go 2 sailors won 3 dollars" is your program supposed to extract 1 2 and 3 ? or is the input supposed to be 1 (and) 2 (and) 3?

Comment: this is probably a bit advanced for you, but using Exceptions and exception handling to let transactions die if the input isn't right can be a good way to handle such problems

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("input integer #"+(i+1)+": ");
        if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            intArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("value for #"+(i+1)+": " + intArray[i]);
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("not an integer");
            break;
        }

    }

    keyboard.close();

 }

}
```

or maybe another solution that asks again when the number was no integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {

        boolean isInputCorrect = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("input integer #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
                intArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("value for #" + (i + 1) + ": " + intArray[i]);
                isInputCorrect = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("not an integer, try again");
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }

        } while (!isInputCorrect);

    }

    keyboard.close();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to answer your question totally but to point you in the right direction. There should be enough here to help you figure out what else is needed for your program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandbox {
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("enter an integer");

    while (true) { //keep prompting the user until they comply
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            keyboard.close();
            break; 
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("You must enter an integer");
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("num: " + num);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would use an **array** or **arrayList** (based on your needs) to store the int values and then use a **while loop** to check and accept the numbers.  while (array.length < 3) do {int checking}.  This way the script will not run if there are already 3 values in the array and will run until you get 3 values.

Comment: That might be a little advanced for this simple example. It seems like the OP is having trouble getting their program to accept another input if the user doesn't enter an integer. In addition, the OP seems like a beginner. Telling them to add a data structure when they are struggling with basic program control isn't super helpful. Remember, the simplest answer is often the best, especially when somebody is first learning.